# Need a WordPress Plugin for Google Analytics, Favicon, Meta Keywords & Description?

Tags: plugins, google-analytics

I am using WordPress for my site and need to add Google Analytics, a favicon, meta keywords, meta descriptions. I searched for plugin that would do this and found different plugins for each. Can anyone suggest me a plugin which can add Google Analytis, a favicon, meta keywords and meta description?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

It is were me I'd **just use different plugins**; not sure if you'll find one that does all of them and if so finding it will be happenstance.

Or **just code it directly into your theme** (unless you are concerned about switching or upgrading themes.)  Each of those is very trivial to do.

Actually these would make *three (3) good additional questions* if you want to ask them:

1. **Adding Google Analytics** to a Theme without using a Plugin?
2. **Adding a Favicon** to a Theme without using a Plugin?
3. **Adding Meta Keywords & Meta Descriptions** to a Theme without using a Plugin?

Actually, **the latter should be done on a page-by-page basis** so an **SEO plugin** or **SEO optimized theme** would probably be best there.

Answer (score 3):

I currently do all of these with different plugins.  There is no need to look for a combined plugin with so many options.

Google Analytics reccomendation - [Google Analytics for Wordpress](http://yoast.com/wordpress/google-analytics/#utm_source=wordpress&utm_medium=plugin&utm_campaign=google-analytics-for-wordpress&utm_content=v407)

Favicon - many themes include this ability (Atahualpa being one)

Meta - any of various SEO plugins as Mike suggested

Hope this helps

MM

Answer (score 1):

The only time I use GA is for one particular client, and I embed the GA code directly into the theme footer.

For favicons, my theme framework has built-in support for this, so if the client wants it, all they have to do is drop an appropriately-name image into the theme's image folder and it works with no further work needed.

For meta tags, I have a custom function I wrote for my theme framework that handles this.  It builds the tags based on either the contents of custom fields on each post/page, or post tags (for keywords) and the post/page content or excerpt (for the description) with defaults assigned through the theme options page.  I uploaded an edited version (to work without my theme framework as a plugin) [here](http://gist.github.com/559269).

Comment: *@Keith S.* Good answers.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be what you are after but I use a premium theme extensively called Thesis which allows for easy implementation of all of your questions.

It has a spot to insert Analytics scripts, a favicon uploader and really nice SEO functionality, all without additional plugins. I thoroughly recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you just add all those yourself manually by coding them directly to your site's theme templates. This way, you don't have to deal with the additional overhead of loading (multiple) plugins into your installation (and we know that some plugins have some bloat to some extent).

The GA code, you'll probably want to add to your `footer.php` file, while the rest would probably go to your `header.php` file.

Only con I can think of is that you'll have to do this everytime you switch a theme --- but for most sites, the choice of theme is basically static anyway, so it's very negligible.